# What do partclone.dd and partclone.imager do differently?

Tags: backup, dd

I'm writing some backup software that needs functionality like `partclone`(8), and having some trouble with the man pages.  In particular, I don't see any difference between the pages for `partclone.dd` and `partclone.imager`, and the two binaries, while different, are the exact same size.  Moreover, I found a question somewhere with an answer that made a distinction between them, but it was not clear why.

So I'm really wanting to know what is different between them.  I had supposed they were just `dd` disguise, but I'm ready to be proven wrong.

Comment: Reading the two man pages side-by-side, I noticed that `partclone.imager` has two extra command-line options: `--clone` and `--restore`.  There is no discussion of what these do, however, and two pages' `EXAMPLES` sections are identical and use `partclone.dd` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran 4 copies of a fairly large EXT4 partition to see what the differences could be.  That, together with some further inside info, seems to settle the matter for me.

The 4 copies I made were by the following programs:

- `partclone.ext4`
- `partclone.dd`
- `partclone.imager`
- `dd` (the real one)

I discovered that the first was by far the smallest, which makes sense because it does not have to back up everything -- just the stuff that is occupied.

I discovered that `partclone.dd` produces exactly the same image that the real `dd` produces.  Just with a different command interface.

I discovered that `partclone.imager` produces a considerably larger image than `dd`, which is consistent with the clone format I found at `https://github.com/Thomas-Tsai/partclone/blob/master/IMAGE_FORMATS.md`.  This includes checksums and bitmaps.

It makes sense to me that in cases where dd could make sense, I'll use `partclone.imager` rather than `dd` because of the added robustness and checking in the event of damage to the backup.

The added parameters `--clone`, `--restore` and `--disk-to-disk` are needed by `partclone.imager` because the image is not identical to the source partition.

Comment: +1+1; Thanks for the thorough tests and explanations :-)

Comment: It also turns out that one never needs the `--restore` argument to `partclone` programs, because the image format is the same for all images made by the `--clone` argument.  Therefore, the `partclone.restore` program is capable of restoring any of them, and this makes the required coding a bit simpler.